# C# - XML reading outside of tags/elements

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a small problem which I'm hoping to get some help resolving. So far I am at a dead end.

This is an example input:

```
<example some="" random="" attributes="" here="">
  <something>
    [01/01/1993 10:10:10] name:
  </something>important text.
</example>
```

I need to get the 'important text' which is positioned where shown. I cannot modify the XML due to it being produced by another application.

Thanks,
Thomas.

PS. My current thoughts are to read all the elements and elements' content and replace it with nothing - this obviously isn't a very good way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("1.xml");
var text = xdoc.Root.Element("something").NextNode as XText;

if (text != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(text.Value);
}
```

This code checks if your next node is XText and not null, which is a good practice in your case.

Answer (score 2):

```
var xText = XDocument.Parse(xmlstr).Root.Nodes().Last() as XText;
var text = xText.Value;
```

OR

```
var text = XDocument.Parse(DATA).Root.Nodes().Last().ToString();
```